# Acceder a tabla pivote laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo unas tablas con una relación muchos a muchos, `properties` y `people`, su tabla pivote es `people_properties`, pero en esta tabla pivote ademas de el id propio, el de `properties` y `people`, tengo otras dos columnas, como hago para acceder a estas?

En cada modelo (Property y Person) tengo el método accesor a su relación (es decir, belongsToMay y/o hasMany respectivamente), en el controlador donde solicito la informacion, intente usar el metodo del modelo, y lo mande a un JSON pero no me mestra infrmacion de la tabla pivote.

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?

Comment: Realice un edit en el que lo explico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de que alguno llegue a presentar el mismo problema, solucione esto con el método `withPivot` en el método accesor a la relación del modelo; quedando algo así:

```
public function people() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'people_properties', 'property_id', 'person_id')
    ->withPivot('principal', 'resident');
}
```